# jcors-loader.js not working in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

**Index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jcors-loader.js"></script>
    <script>
        JcorsLoader.load(
                "js/jquery-1.8.0.js",
                "/js/alertme.js",
                function() {
                    $("#result").text("TEST OK");
                }
        );

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1 id="result"></h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**alertme.js**

```
alert("Loaded");
```

This works fine in chrome and firefox it displays "TEST OK" and popup...But no message or alert in IE(7,8,9)...Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try putting the script at the bottom of the page rather than in the header.

Comment: tried it placing before </body> still not working

Answer (score 1):

I wrote that library, remember these three tips to use it.

- Not invoke a script add the inline content.
- Put the script tag after the .
- IE7 works but blocks onload.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to check is that you're not using `console.log` anywhere in your javascript as this can cause funny issues with IE.

The next thing to do is check the documentation on the library you're using as it may not be compatible with IE 9 and below (have you tried it with IE 10?)

Comment: Its supported in Safari, Chrome, Firefox, Opera, IE6+. https://github.com/pablomoretti/jcors-loader

Comment: I am not using console.log anywhere.